# Save value of Int (Shared Preference)

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm new to java. I've made a counter which goes up as user holds on a button. I want the app to start with int value of where it left. I know SharedPreference is the way to go but I've no idea how to use it. I'm not sure where to put which part of SharedPreference. Thank you.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button;
int count = 1;
TextView text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
           count++;
            text.setText(String.valueOf(count));
        return false;
        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following function to your activity

```
 public int getValue(String key) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int value = sharedPref.getInt(key, 0);
        return value;
 }
 public void saveValue(String key, int value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putInt(key, value);
        editor.commit();
 }
```

Some code added in your `onCreate()` method

```
final String key = "somekey";
count  = getValue(key); //get value from sharedPreference
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
text.setText(String.valueOf(count)); // set it first
button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        count++;
        saveValue(key,count);
        text.setText(String.valueOf(count));
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try turning

```
int count = 1;
```

into

```
static int count = 1;
```

I'm also somewhat a Java noobie so this may or may not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this,save `count` in SharedPreference when destroy the activity and read value from SharedPreference when you create it:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;
    int count = 1;
    TextView text;
    SharedPreferences sh;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        sh = getSharedPreferences("sh_name", MODE_PRIVATE);
        count = sh.getInt("count", 1);

        button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                count++;
                text.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        sh.edit().putInt("count", count).apply();
    }
}
```